# Android fragment push in Stack then pop but display exception

Tags: android, stack, fragment

My application has three main tab fragments, my design is to push the current into the stack and then add the new fragment and show. But what puzzled me is after a clicked on the current fragment and then go back to the current one the view overflowed the screen. As the application launched the fragment works well once clicked back the display exception.

before clicking the white block :
[image: View before clicking the white block]

after the return back :
[image: View after return back]

Following the two images there's maybe something wrong with the insets parameters. Then I reviewed the code about the after-clicking action and the return but found nothing. Also nothing about the main Activity. I debugged in the flow and tried logging in the main position but the problem is still.

As debugging the code the pushed fragment and the poped were the same compared to the id when in and out.
I've no idea now, Anyone any ideas are appreciated.